Proof: The Variation of $V_{F_{\mu}}$ is finite.
Background Information
Suppose that $\mu$ is a finite signed measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Define a function $F_{\mu}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by letting
$$
F_{\mu}(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])\tag1
$$
hold at each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
It is known that $F_{\mu}$ is of finite variation; that is, the function $V_{F_{\mu}}(-\infty,+\infty) = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F_{\mu}(t_i) - F_{\mu}(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\} < +\infty$, where $\mathscr{S}$ is the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
$$
-\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n < +\infty.
$$
If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation, then we define the function $V_F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by letting $V_F(x)=V_F(-\infty,x]$.

My Question
I would like to prove:

$V_{F_{\mu}}$ is of finite variation.

That is, I want to show that
$$
V_{V_{F_{\mu}}}(-\infty,+\infty) = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|V_{F_{\mu}}(t_i)-V_{F_{\mu}}(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\} < +\infty.
$$
But I got stuck. Honestly, I am not 100% sure whether this statement is correct or not. Could someone help me with it? Is this statement true? If so, how should I prove it? Thank you very much in advance!

@Masacroso Why is $\lim_{x\to\infty}V_F(x)=V_{V_F}(-\infty,+\infty)$?

@Masacroso Sorry, I still didn't get your point. Could you please elaberate it in an answer? I really appreciate it!
